# Javascript alternative for this (IE)

Tags: javascript, iframe, this, attachevent

I have something like the following code:

```
for(var i=0;i<4;i++) {
  frm = document.createElement("iframe");
  frm.width = "100";
  frm.height = "100";
  frm.src = "source.php";
  frm.id = "something";

  frm.attachEvent("load", function() { alert(this.id); //Here I need alternative for this.id });

  var frameDiv = document.getElementById("frameDiv");
  frameDiv.appendChild(frm);
}
```

It's simplified, but basicly it creates four iframes inside some div and I need to fire some actions based on the id of each frame, when it's completely loaded. It works well, but the problem is in IE. IE doesn't know operator this, so I can't access to the id of frame inside. Is there any alternative which I can use for IE?

Thanks for any help!

---

Abhijit: Actually, the whole code is like this:

```
if(frm.addEventListener) {
  frm.addEventListener("load", function() { alert(this.id); },false);
}
  else if(frm.attachEvent) {
  frm.attachEvent("onload", function() { alert(this.id); });
}
  else {
  frm.onload=function() { alert(this.id); };
}
```

So it should works in all browsers.

Comment: What do you mean with *IE doesn't know operator this*? (a) `this` is not an operator, it is a keyword(?) (b) Of course `this` exists in IE (it is part of JScript). But `this` might point to something else than the iframe (althought it should not). What does `this` point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work in IE, but changing

```
frm.attachEvent("load", function() { alert(this.id); });
```

to

```
// wrap in an anonymous function to fix scope issues
(function(frm) {
    frm.attachEvent("load", function() { alert(frm.id); });
})(frm);
```

should give you a consistent reference to the iframe.

(**Edit**: Updated above code to fix scope issues within the loop. This is exactly why you should generally avoid creating closures in a loop like this - all `frm` references will point to the last defined iframe unless you take explicit measures to fix the scope.)

Comment: it is in a loop so all events will use the same value for `frm` .. (*the last one assigned*)

Comment: @Gaby - very true - clearly not paying attention. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: +1 for this. You could also wrap the callback in a parser like so: `frm.attachEvent('load', function(e){callback.apply(frm, [e])});`. Then `this` will refer to the frame element in the callback. You'd still need the closure though.

Answer (score 1):

`frm.attachEvent("load", function() { alert(this.id); });`, this should be `frm.attachEvent("onload", function() { alert(this.id); });`. In IE you can get the element as event.srcElement. So your code could be `frm.attachEvent("onload", function(event) { alert(event.srcElement.id); });`

Comment: This will only work if you pass the event into the function: `frm.attachEvent("onload", function(event) { alert(event.srcElement.id); });`

Comment: IE event object is global, so it should work even if we don't pass the event object to the function. But passing the event is a good thing, especially for events like click and mouse events that may fire for a number of elements. I have updated the code, thanks.